# How do I create a project inside of a space in Phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

In Phabricator, I want to create a project inside a space or want to assign an existing project to a space, but I can't find a way to do so.
I want to make sure whether or not I am missing something before creating a new task at [Phacility](https://secure.phabricator.com/).

Update: I found the closed task [T8493](https://secure.phabricator.com/T8493) that is dealing with the topic and I created [T10254](https://secure.phabricator.com/T10254).

Comment: Please share the link if you create a task at [Phacility](https://secure.phabricator.com/), I am dealing with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to assign a project to a space right now, see the tasks on Phacility mentioned in the updated question.

But there is a way to deal the problem I use: I have "parent" projects for the teams in our company. No one can join or leave those projects, only the admins can manage memberships. Then we have different "inner" projects that are visible and joinable for the members of the regarding parent project. The repositories and tasks are then visible for members of the inner projects. Users can choose which inner projects within their team area they need.

This way one could also deal with more than two nested levels.

Comment: " (...) The repositories and tasks are then visible for members of the inner projects. (...)" How do you take care that the tasks and repos are only visible for members of the inner projects? Manually or is there an automatic way?

Comment: Yes, right now we need to do this manually. But there is a feature called [forms](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/forms/) that sounds quite interesting for that. Unfortunately I had no time to give it a try.

Comment: You can use forms, generally this works to set spaces or visibility. However, I cannot use this approach because in the Phabricator instance I am using there is a high number of projects that all have different visibility requirements. I would like to have a custom Herald rule which can set spaces based on the project but I have no experience in PHP to write an extension.